# Calculate total time in minutes between two timings in two diff. time zones (UTC and IST) - Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, ruby-2.0

I have two datetimes formats to calculate the difference.

```
2013-08-29 22:48:00 UTC
2013-08-30 00:18:40 +0530
```

How can I get the first subtracted from the second one? What is actually the difference between them other than in time?

Below are the things I run in my console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)

2.0.0-p247 :001 > @a = Time.parse('2013-08-29 22:48:00 UTC')
 => 2013-08-29 22:48:00 UTC 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > @b = Time.parse('2013-08-29 22:48:00 +0530')
 => 2013-08-29 22:48:00 +0530 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > @a > @b
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > @a == @b
 => false 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > @a < @b
 => false 
2.0.0-p247 :006 >
```

Both are not the same, so the answer from [cmwright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657097/cmwright) is found to be incorrect. Please have a look and it would be great if you could tell me how can we convert UTC format to +5.30 format in Rails 3.2?

Comment: You're doing a string comparison, not a date one

Comment: As @FrederickCheung suggests above, your issue is that comparing the actual string, not using the `Time` class to do the comparison for you. If you do as I suggest below and set @a and @b to Time instances you should be good to go

Answer (score 2):

`seconds_difference = Time.parse('2013-08-29 22:48:00 UTC') - Time.parse('2013-08-30 00:18:40 +0530')`

Will give you the seconds difference, then you can get you need from there by doing

`seconds_difference / 1.day` or `seconds_difference / 1.hour`

Comment: why we are subtracting a higher date from a lower date? Also what could be the difference between the above two formats?

Comment: You can switch the order if you like, but if you want an absolute result (always positive) you'll want to call `.abs` on it

Answer (score 1):

> What is actually the difference between them other than in time?

Well, one date is at UTC (+00:00) and the other is at UTC+05:30.

```
  2013-08-29 22:48:00 UTC   =>     2013-08-30 04:18:00 +0530
- 2013-08-29 18:48:40 UTC   <=   - 2013-08-30 00:18:40 +0530
-------------------------        ---------------------------
              3:59:20                          3:59:20
```

Whichever direction you convert, they are 3 hours, 59 minutes, and 20 seconds apart.

CMWright's answer shows how you can subtract them in code.  The integers you get from the `Time.parse` function are both based on UTC.

Comment: yes, I agree. Can you please tell me how can I convert a time in UTC to +0530 format (in Rails specifically)?